# Subscribing to an observable every 5 seconds and stop when condition is met in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using angular and in my component I am doing the following since the product could take up to 5 seconds to insert in the backend

```
this.productService.insert(this.product).subscribe(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
         this.refreshList();
         this.res = res;
         this.enableButton = true;
    }, 5000);
}, err => {

});
```

Is there anyway I can improve on this code? I see a bunch of posts using Observable.interval and takeWhile. With the above solution I am unable to make it repeat if condition is not met and stop if condition is met.

Below is an updated version I am trying to do:

```
public myFunction(): void {
    this.disableButton = true;

    this.productService.insert(this.product)
    .switchMap(_ => Observable.timer(5000)
    .do(this.refreshList)).takeWhile(() => this.productList.length === 0).subscribe(res => {
        this.result = res;
        this.disableButton = false;
    }, err => {
        // handle error messages
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the content of `res`? Usually when you post a new resource to a remote API, the backend first persists the resource and then responds, usually by returning the same object updated with an id value.

Comment: Combined with @Siri0S comment, wouldn't the `res` let you know when the product has been inserted successfully?

Comment: @Siri0S It returns the added product. Currently I don't need to use it for anything though.

Comment: Well, if the added product has a unique id, it means that it has been persisted in the database so you don't have to wait for anything. You just have to refresh the list of products.

Comment: @Siri0S There is a lot more going on in my actual scenario. I just used product as an example. I am actually processing something in the backend that takes time. So if refreshList is called too fast it will be empty. I misinformed you about res, res just tells me the process has started, nothing more.

Comment: Well you need to find a better mechanism. Relying on a timer for something asynchronous is really not a good idea. Don't you have any return that might be helpful to know when your operations are done?

Comment: could you chain your observables? so it would be `service1.subscribe(res => {service2.subscribe( res2 => this.refreshList() )});` so that you aren't waiting on two calls to finish at once?

Comment: @rhavelka I am not sure if this would help in my case. The first observable kicks off a process and responds immediately saying that the process successfully started. The next step would be to continuously make calls every 5 seconds to refresh list until something is finally returned. The refresh list function makes calls to the Db and if the items from the insert are not in there yet I would like to call it again and again until something is returned.

Comment: @rhavelka I understand it would be ideal if the insert simply returned the inserted object once it is finished then I could simply do a push to the existing list on the page. But I am unable to change what the insert returns. It just returns a status saying the process started. Which leaves me with no choice but to keep pinging the refresh list function over over again until it returns something.

Comment: Might want to consider making `refreshList()` return a Promise/Observable so that you can do the "next thing" once `refreshList()` is done. ...instead of polling.

Answer (score 1):

Observable.timer should do what you wanted.

```
 this.productService.insert(this.product)
.switchMap(res =>Observable.timer(5000).do(this.refreshList))
.takeWhile(()=>your condition...).subscribe()
```

Edit: do:

```
public myFunction(): void {
    this.disableButton = true;

    this.productService.insert(this.product)
    .switchMap(_ => Observable.timer(5000)
    .do(this.refreshList),(res=>res)).takeWhile(() => this.productList.length === 0).subscribe(res => {
        this.result = res;
        this.disableButton = false;
    }, err => {
        // handle error messages
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: this is in the direction of what I need but for some reason the insert call from productService is not working now. So something is not right. I made the condition the following: () => this.productList.length !== 0. Also I am a bit confused we are using switchMap instead of subscribe?

Comment: sorry i missed the subcribe at the end of the line. You do need it. switchMap is for flattening and executing the inner observable.

Comment: where do I access the result of the .insert ? In the final subscribe?

Comment: Please see my original using set timeout. I want to call refreshList every 5 seconds while this.productList.length === 0 but additionally need to set this.res to the res of the insert subscription and do a few other things like enable a button on the page. After adding .subscribe the insert is working because when I refresh the page I see the item, but the re-enabling of the button and refreshlist are not working.

Comment: give me a sec I am updating my post.

Comment: I added the version with your code to the bottom of my post. Let me know if anything looks wrong. By the way refreshList will populate productList so it will make it so the condition is not met anymore and stop calling refreshList.

Comment: All u have to do is to add a result selector to swithmap. Switchmap(res=>timer().do(),res=>res)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173226/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-fan-cheung).

Comment: Result selector let u decide what to pass on after switchmap, try to Google switchmap result selector

Comment: do you mind updating your answer so this.result can be set to res returned from the insert call? And additionally where this.enableButton = true; code can be set. I am not sure where these 2 lines would go with your format.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: all seems to be good now except for one thing. The insert is working, but refreshList must not be running because the list in the UI isn't getting updated. Maybe my condition is invalid. When that condition isn't met is when it stops correct?

Comment: I see what is going on. I am calling this.productService inside of the refreshList() function and subscribing to it. It is undefined when using your function. Does dependency injection not work in this case or something? It works every other time the function is called.

Comment: I think u are getting there , very close

Comment: yeah I agree but do you know why my service inside of refreshList is undefined only when refreshList is called through your example.

Comment: Do(()=>this.refreshlist